# How do I access a nested value in a one-to-many related field, within a multidimensional JavaScript array object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, multidimensional-array, prisma

I have an Object called `universe` that looks like this:

**Universes**

```
[
    {
        "id": "cl94en0hs1x",
        "title": "My Universe",
        "published": false,
        "authorId": "cl94elyqvpl6bf",
        "author": {
            "name": "Jane"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "cl94hlv5t028z",
        "title": "My other Universe",
        "published": false,
        "authorId": "cl94elyq",
        "author": {
            "name": "Jacob"
        }
    }
]
```

Each universe has a **1 to many** relationship with another Object called `Planet`. (One universe can have many planets, but a planet can only belong to one universe.) This connection is seen by the field `universeId` in the `Planet` object, showing which universe the planet belongs to. See the planet object further below

When I am in an individual Universe, I can access the planets that the universe has, using include and [select](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/select-fields) in Prisma like so:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (x: { params: { id: String} }) => {
    const universe = await prisma.universe.findUnique({
        where: {
            id: String(x.params?.id)
        },
        include: {
            planets: {
                select: {
                    title: true,
                   id: true,
                },
            },
            author: {
                select: { name: true, email: true },
            },
        },
    });
    return {
        props: universe,
    };
};
```

Then to get an individual planet object I use `planets[0]` which gives me the result below.

**Planet**

```
        {
            "title": "Earth",
            "id": "c4bd6e18c9564fde920cc0f85d4c0cbc"
        }
```

**Problem**

The problem I have is, I am trying to extract `title` and `id` from the planet object above so that I can save them as individual variables and use them. For example, I need the `id` field in order to navigate to the individual planet.

I can't seem to drill down any further after `planets[0]`, so how do I drill down further to get id?

i tried `planets[0][0]` for `title` and `planets[0][1]` (this doesn't work, it's probably stupid, but i'm trying everything). Also tried `planets[0].id`, `planets.id`. None of them works.

I also tried looping over it, Object.Keys, Object.Entry. But I can not seem to get an individual value like  `c4bd6e18c9564fde920cc0f85d4c0cbc` for the id. The closest I came to was:

```
id: c4bd6e18c9564fde920cc0f85d4c0cbc
```

**How do I get the value only?**

I want this:

```
c4bd6e18c9564fde920cc0f85d4c0cbc
```

Answer (score 0):

You use flat maps for your work efficiently.
The flatMap() method returns a new array formed by applying a given callback function to each element of the array, and then flattening the result by one level. (Ref: Mozilla)

Comment: Hi hamza, thanks a lot. Could you expand? How can I use it with my code?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might be interested, it ended up being a small thing I missed before. I would have deleted the question, but StackOverflow said I should leave it for fairness purposes, and in case someone needs it.

```
planets[0].id
```

This gives me the value i needed: `c4bd6e18c9564fde920cc0f85d4c0cbc`